# How to have calendar popup in a form field of 'date' type?

Tags: 8, forms

Using Drupal Console, I created a custom content entity in which there is a 'date' field:

```
$fields['subscription_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')  
  ->setLabel(t('Date souscription'))  
  ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'date')  
  ->setDefaultValue(array(0 => array(  
    'default_date_type' => 'now',  
    'default_date' => 'now',  
  )))
```

The edit-form works as supposed and, particularly, editing 'subscription_date' brings up the calendar popup:
[image]
In my custom module, I defined a table form to 'mass' edit this entity:
I defined the date field in the form this way:

```
$form['souscriptions'][$key]['date'] = array(  
    '#type' => 'date',  
    '#default_value' => $default_value,  
);
```

In Firefox, it looks like:
[image]
and editing a date field doesn't show the date popup :-(
While in Chrome, it's OK:
[image]
Any idea why?
What should I add to my form to have at least the simple calendar popup I have in my content entity edit-form?

Forgot to say: i'm using Drupal 8.4.2

Answer (score 1):

This issue is coming because of jQuery confliction. 
Either you can update jQuery version or find out the confliction of jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because at the time you asked this question, Firefox did not implement HTML5 date popup picker yet. As of right now Firefox already has it, but Safari for example still does not. To make the calendar popup work on browsers like Safari you would need some sort of a JavaScript solution such as [jQuery UI date picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)